# how can i use group_by in text mining with r

Tags: r, text-mining

I am just wondering why I cant use `group_by()` in corpus-text.
I tried using some packages too but at the end nothing.
Also tried to convert to tibble.

My code:

```
data <- data %>%
  group_by(Title) %>%
  mutate(line = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The output:

```
Error:
! All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
✖ Column `text` is a `corpus_text` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Can you please share the data in the `data` object? See this for some help on sharing data on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.